# MythTV Backend Setup Guide Ubuntu Server 12.10

Tags: server, mythtv

I have tried a handful of guides for installation, but I can't seem to get any of them to work.  My ideal solution would be mythtv-backend running on Ubuntu Server connecting to the cmyth pvr plugin on XBMC.

Guides I've used:
http://beckustech.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/setting-up-a-home-server-with-ubuntu-11-10-part-2-mythtv/
http://blog.andrewmanugian.com/2009/07/26/andrewsmythtvguide/#listings

I've started from scratch with fresh installs of Ubuntu several times, and I have never been able to get the front end to connect.  I've changed the IP address setting in mythtv-setup and my.cnf.  I have also run several different combinations of dpkg-reconfigure.  I've been fighting with this so long, I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

One final question - any time I try to run mythtv-setup via ssh it prompts for a password.  Anything I type is the wrong password - which is problematic - because I don't have X installed on this machine.  Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea what.

tl;dr;

How do I set up mythtv-backend on Ubuntu Server 12.10 for remote connections?
What's the secret to running mythtv-setup over ssh?

Answer (score 1):

All things being equal, on a fresh installation of Ubuntu, running:

```
sudo apt-get install mythtv-backend-master
```

will install your MythTV master backend server. Unless you have done odd things to your network (or other) configuration, this will automatically expose the relevant services for remote connections from other machines on your local network.

To run `mythtv-setup` on your backend from another machine, you need to run:

```
ssh -X mythtv@yourservername mythtv-setup
```

This will run `mythtv-setup` as the `mythtv` user. You may need to set a password for the mythtv user on your server before you can log in using it.

One thing to remember is that this method still requires an X Server running on the machine you are connecting from.